# star rating radio buttons css

Tags: html, css

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghvNn/261/ I create a two star ratings. It´s from this webpage http://rog.ie/blog/css-star-rater. But this code is only for 5 stars, but I would like to have it UNIVERSAL CODE (3,5,7,10) stars. How can I do it?

```
<span class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
<br><br>
<span class="star-rating">      
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Just decrease the width of the container

Comment: Lol. Just remove/add some of the `input`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add extra class to `span.star-rating` to separate styles of the stars with different count. ex:

```
<span class="star-rating star-5">
```

then **REMOVE** this style :

```
.star-rating {width: 250px;}
.star-rating i {width: 20%;}
.star-rating input {width: 20%;}
```

and last you can add this styles :

```
.star-rating.star-5 {width: 250px;}
.star-rating.star-5 input,
.star-rating.star-5 i {width: 20%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i {width: 40%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i {width: 60%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i {width: 80%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~i {width: 100%;}

.star-rating.star-3 {width: 150px;}
.star-rating.star-3 input,
.star-rating.star-3 i {width: 33.33%;}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i {width: 66.66%;}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i ~ i {width: 100%;}
```

**DEMO :** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAVpz/)

Answer (score 2):

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghvNn/263/)

Here you have a code for 10 stars

HTML:

```
 <span class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="6"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="7"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="8"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="9"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="10"><i></i>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background:     url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 1;
  background:     url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
  width: 20%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 30%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 50%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 70%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 90%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
::after,
::before {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

As you can see all you need to do is add input elements in HTML and then in CSS change a width of .star-rating element and add proper width value in percentage to every 'i' element.